# Spark 1.5.1 standalone cluster - wrong Akka remoting config?

Tags: apache-spark, akka, akka-remote-actor

Doing my firsts steps with Spark, I'm facing problems submitting jobs to cluster from the application code. Digging the logs, I noticed some periodic WARN messages on master log:

```
15/10/08 13:00:00 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.254.167:64014] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]
```

The problem is that ip address not exist on our network, and wasn't configured anywhere. The same wrong ip is shown on the worker log when it tries execute the task (wrong ip passed to --driver-url):

```
15/10/08 12:58:21 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/java/latest//bin/java" "-cp" "/path/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-ha
doop2.6/sbin/../conf/:/path/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/path/spark/
spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/path/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.ja
r:/path/spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/path/hadoop/2.6.0//etc/hadoop/" "-Xms102
4M" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=64014" "-Dspark.driver.port=53411" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url"
"akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.254.167:64014/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "--executor-id" "39" "--hostname" "192.168.10.214" "--cores" "16" "--app-id"  "app-20151008123702-0003" "--worker-url" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@192.168.10.214:37625/user/Worker"
15/10/08 12:59:28 INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20151008123702-0003/39 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
```

Any idea what I did wrong and how can this be fixed?

The java version is 1.8.0_20, and I'm using pre-built Spark binaries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will give you some clues here at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024325/spark-1-5-1-standalone-cluster-exception-in-thread-main-akka-actor-actornotf/33027284#33027284) which is similar question to yours with "**Association with remote system has failed**"