# Spark 1.5.1 standalone cluster - Exception in thread "main" akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for

Tags: apache-spark

I'm facing problems submitting jobs to the cluster, either by spark-submit or from java code. Jobs keep failing, and the stderr logs (under SPARK_HOME/work/app_id..) always show the same error:

```
15/10/08 23:04:39 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@masternode:53411] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@masternode:53411]] Caused by: [Connection refused: masternode/192.168.10.214:53411]
Exception in thread "main" akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://sparkDriver@masternode:53411/), Path(/user/MapOutputTracker)]
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:65)
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:73)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:74)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:120)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:266)
    at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:533)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:569)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:559)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:87)
    at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.postStop(Endpoint.scala:557)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPostStop(Actor.scala:477)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundPostStop(Endpoint.scala:411)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:210)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Any clue what might cause that? Running netstat shows that no process listens on port 53411.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the error msg:

> Association with remote system
>   [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@masternode:53411] has failed

is telling you that the master worker communication has problems.

I got this error before, and my suggestion would be:

1. make sure your master address is right , check the [master url here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/submitting-applications.html#master-urls)
2. check your firewall, iptable to make sure the port is not blocked. Spark will use some random port number to communicate
3. make sure that your memory is big enough, if not enough resource it will sometimes generate similar error too

You can monitor your cluster status at port 4040 and 18080, maybe it will also give you some useful clue.

```
http://<server-url>:18080

http://<driver-node>:4040
```